# Information about blender and its computer

Tags: scripting

how r u, please can you me that which computer is best for Blender 2.8 for best result and which computer you use, What is specification of your computer, waiting for reply, thanks

Comment: Opinions on hardware and discussions of brands are considered off-topic on this site. A forum like https://blenderartists.org might work better for the information you are looking for.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because hardware recommendations are considered off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow this link to the Blender 2.8 Beta Hardware requirements page.
https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/

Hope that answers your question. If not, please come back!

Answer (score 0):

blender is very flexible with hardware requirements, the is no way to get "the best" computer for blender unless you have access to a NASA computer, just always try to get a better graphics card and a better processor if possible